# Category - "No content found"

Tags: php, html

so here is my problem:

```
get_header();

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <article class="post">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a') ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"></a> | Posted in

                <?php

                $categories = get_the_category();
                $seperator = ", ";
                $output = '';

                if ($categories) {

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {

                        $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>' . $seperator;

                    }

                    echo trim($output, $seperator);

                }

                ?>

            </p>

            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </article>

        <?php endwhile;

        else :
            echo '<p>No content found</p>';

        endif;

get_footer();
```

This code is supposed to work but it's not working and I don't know why. Basically, when I click on a "News" Category that I made in WordPress, it brings me to it, on the URL Bar it says "/category/news". My point is that when I click on that Category the page shows "No content found"... Please help.

Comment: Also wanted to add that this is index.php

Comment: Does this category actually contain anything?

Comment: Yes, it contains three posts, well supposed to contain three posts, but it does not display them. It only displays "No content found"

Comment: Did you put the above code in a file named category.php ?

Comment: @samuel I had just made a file named category.php and inserted the above code into it. Still says "No content found".

Comment: Make sure that 'news' contains some content.. test the '/category/uncategorized' if you have it there. Your code works, I have just tested it..

Comment: @samuel I had made a youtube video to show you that I have content in the posts. YT - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9M0GIX8E8Q&feature=youtu.be

Comment: And your `functions.php` `header.php` and plugins contain no calls to `query_posts`, and no filters on `pre_get_posts`, does this happen with the standard default theme?

Comment: @TomJNowell I had never checked that and probably I will not know how to since I'm a newb to WordPress. Could that problem be caused by a Mac localhost? Or just the Localhost? (I'm working on my iMac)

Comment: localhost has nothing to do with my previous comment in any way shape or form, you can check for calls to `query_posts` by searching for `query_posts` in your theme with your editor, same with `pre_get_posts`. You can test if it happens with the default theme, by activating the default theme. You can test it's not a plugin by deactivating all your plugins